# filtering a list in R

Tags: r, list, filtering, curve-fitting, bayesian-networks

I'm going Bayesian knowledge tracing in R right now, and part of my code needs to eliminate students that have less than 3 instances on a given KC otherwise the parameter estimates won't converge. So to do that, I currently have:

```
by_user = split(one_kc, one_kc$Anon.Student.id)
obs_by_user = sapply(by_user, nrow)
valid_users = names(obs_by_user[obs_by_user > 2])
student_outcomes = one_kc[one_kc$Anon.Student.id %in% valid_users,]
```

But for some reason, when I look at by_user in my environment, the invalid users are still listed in there and if I try and run the curve fitting, the values don't converge and I believe this is the reason. Where am I going wrong?

edit: here is more of the code that I am working with currently:

```
df <- data.frame(read.table(file=file.choose(),na.strings="NA",sep="\t",quote="",header=TRUE, fill=TRUE))


df_subset <- df[,c(5,21,27,39,38)]

df_subset$Accuracy <- as.numeric(as.vector(df_subset$Accuracy))

df_subset <- na.omit(df_subset)

kc_list <- unique(df_subset$KC.Model.2A.)
#loop on the kc_list
for (kc in kc_list)
  {
  print(kc)
  one_kc <- df_subset[ which(df_subset$KC.Model.2A.==kc), ]
  one_kc <- one_kc[,c(1,3)]
  # remove users with few observations on this skill
  by_user = split(one_kc, one_kc$Anon.Student.id)
  obs_by_user = sapply(by_user, nrow)
  valid_users = names(obs_by_user[obs_by_user > 2])
  student_outcomes = one_kc[one_kc$Anon.Student.id %in% valid_users,]

  by_good_user = split(student_outcomes$Accuracy, student_outcomes$Anon.Student.id)
}
```

Comment: you might want to have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  about a minimal working example. It would be really helpful if you post the general structure of your data.

ie.
`df <- data.frame(Anon.Student.id = 1:10,
                            Accuracy = rnorm(10))`
So that we are able to reproduce your issue!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to speed-up the code you can also look into the data.table package:

```
library(data.table)
new_kc_dt <- as.data.table(new_kc)

new_kc_dt[, instances := .N, by = Anon.Student.id][instances >= 3]

# which is the same as 
new_kc_dt[, instances := .N, by = Anon.Student.id]
new_kc_dt[instances >= 3]
```

Comment: You could probably just do `setDT(new_kc)[, if(.N >= 3) .SD, by = Anon.Student.id]`. Where did you get that data set from btw?

Comment: The data set is just an inserted excel spreadsheet formatted as a tab delimited txt file. Is there a way to do this without using a new library? cause that tends to reformat the data in a way that the rest of the program can't handle

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
new_kc <- one_kc %>%
    group_by(Anon.Student.id) %>%
    mutate(instances = n()) %>%
    filter(instances >= 3)
```

Comment: So this works, but it changes how the data is stored so now it doesn't work for the rest of my program. Is there a way to keep the formatting the same but just take out the ones with less than 3 instances?

Comment: right now, unfiltered, it's a list of vectors:

    df_subset$Accuracy <- as.numeric(as.vector(df_subset$Accuracy))

Comment: That's a different problem than the one you initially asked about, and it's hard to give a confident answer without having your data or a piece of it in the original structure.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I will edit my original post with a larger chunk of my code for you.

Comment: It's really hard to work through this with no sample data, just from reading code, but you might try rerunning that `split()` operation on the data produced by my little block of code and seeing if that does it.

Comment: now, the ones with 0 instances are still showing up, and I'm back to what I had before. I'm not sure why this is though because I can see the place where it should be removing those students, yet it's not doing so